# GCP container push not working - "denied: Please enable Google Container Registry API in Cloud Console at ..."

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm having trouble uploading my docker image to GCP Container registry.  I was following the [instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling).

As you can see in the screenshot below, I've:

1. Logged into my google cloud shell and built a docker image via a dockerfile
2. Tagged my image correctly (I think)
3. Tried to push the image using the correct command (I think)

[image: Docker push to GCP screenshot]

However, I'm getting this error:
denied:

```
Please enable Google Container Registry API in Cloud Console at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/containerregistry.googleapis.com/overview?project=bentestproject-184220 before performing this operation.
```

When I follow that link, it takes me to the wrong project:

[image]

When I select my own project, I can see that "Google Container Registry API" is indeed enabled:

[image]

How do I upload my docker images?

Comment: Seems like the push is going to the wrong project... make sure you set the correct project in Cloud Shell by using "gcloud config set project <project ID>" first.

Answer (score 21):

I seems that you mistype you project ID. You project name is BensTestsProject but ID is bentestproject-184220.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue and solved it. In my case the project name in the image tag was wrong. you must be re-check your "bentestproject-184220" in your image tag is correctly your projectID.